# Flutter - SQFlite - type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to display some data of the sqflite database, but I do always get the `snapshot.error` :

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'double'

I do not really know, how I am producing this type of error. Could somebody please explain to me how it is possible to solve this kind of error.

This is the futurebuilder:

```
new FutureBuilder<List<Recipes>>(
          future: fetchRecipes(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(snapshot.data[index].id.toString(),
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                          new Text(snapshot.data[index].name,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0)),
                          new Divider()
                        ]);
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return new Container(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          },
        ),
      )
```

,this is the model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class RecipesDB{
  RecipesDB();

  int id, favorite;
  double duration;
  dynamic image;
  String name, definition, timestamp;

  static final columns = ["id", "name", "definition","duration", "favorite", "timestamp", "image"];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "name": name,
      "definition": definition,      
      "duration": duration,
      "favorite": favorite,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "image": image
    };

    if(id != null){
      map["id"] = id;
    }

    return map;
  }

  static fromMap(Map map){
    RecipesDB recipes = new RecipesDB();

    recipes.id = map["id"];
    recipes.name = map["name"];
    recipes.definition = map["definition"];
    recipes.duration = map["duration"];
    recipes.favorite = map["favorite"];
    recipes.timestamp = map["timestamp"];
    recipes.image = map["image"];

    return recipes;
  }
}


class Recipes{
  int id, favorite;
  double duration;
  dynamic image;
  String name, definition, timestamp;

  Recipes(this.name, this.definition, this.duration, this.favorite, this.timestamp, this.image);
}
```

and this is the function to gather the data:

```
Future<List<Recipes>> getRecipes() async{
    List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recipes");
    List<Recipes> recipes = new List();
    for(int i =0; i < list.length; i++){
      recipes.add(new Recipes(list[i]["name"], list[i]["definition"], list[i]["duration"], list[i]["favorite"], list[i]["timestamp"], list[i]["image"]));      
    }

    return recipes;
  }
```

It would be very helpful, if somebody would be able to solve my problem.

Thanks in advanceXD

Comment: Can you actually post your code?

Comment: you are missing toString() at the end of snapshot.data[index].name

Comment: It is still showing up the same error

Comment: Can you provide the code that actually saves these values into sqflite? Duration might be being saved as a String

Comment: You were right. Duration is saved as string. I have changed that and now I am trying if it is working.

Comment: It worked. Thank you  for your fast reply and solution.!!!!!

Comment: I'm going to post this as answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duration should be being saved as String. Change that to double and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Save it as a String, then when you want to show the data, use `double.parse(widget.recipes.duration)` instead of `widget.recipes.duration`. Works for my project.